# Display many-to-many table data using view model in controller in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, many-to-many, asp.net-core-identity

I want to display many-to-many table data using a view model in controller but I get this error:

> **[CS0029](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0029?f1url=%3FappId%3Droslyn%26k%3Dk(CS0029))**: Cannot implicitly convert type 'Website.Model.PostModel' to 'System.Collections.GenericList<Website.Model.PostModel>'

`Model`:

```cs
public class PostModel
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public List<TagsModel> Tags { get; set; } = new List<TagsModel>();
    public virtual List<PostTagModel> PostTags { get; set; } = new List<PostTagModel>();
}

public class TagsModel
{        
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public List<PostModel> Posts { get; set; }
    public virtual List<PostTagModel> PostTags { get; set; }
}

public class PostTagModel
{
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public int TagId { get; set; }

    public virtual PostModel Post { get; set; }
    public virtual TagsModel Tag { get; set; }
}
```

`ViewModel`:

```cs
public class CardsViewModel
{
    public List<PostModel>? PostCard { get; set; }
}
```

`Controller`:

```cs
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Detail(int id)
{
    var TaggedPostVM = new CardsViewModel
    {
        PostCard = await _context.Posts.Include(t => t.PostTags) 
                                    .ThenInclude(p => p.Post)
                                    .SingleAsync(t => t.Id == id);
    };

    return View(TaggedPostVM);
}
```

`View`:

```html
@using RecipeWebsite.ViewModels.CardsViewModel

@model CardsViewModel

@foreach (var item in Model.PostCard)
{
   <!-- HTML -->
}
```

When the controller is used without view model, it works without error.

`Example`:

```cs
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Detail(int id)
{
    var Tag = await _context.Posts
                            .Include(t => t.PostTags) 
                            .ThenInclude(p => p.Post)
                            .SingleAsync(t => t.Id == id);

    return View(Tag);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you defined the PostCard property in `CardsViewModel` as a `List<PostModel>`, but in your controller you tried to pass a PostModel object to it, which causing the error.

If you want to pass a list of PostModel objects, you can modify the controller to return a list, here is an example you can use as a reference:

My controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Detail(int id)
{
    var taggedPosts = await _context.Posts
                   .Include(t => t.PostTags)
                   .Where(t => t.Id == id)
                   .ToListAsync();

    var TaggedPostVM = new CardsViewModel
    {
        PostCard = taggedPosts
    };

    return View(TaggedPostVM);
}
```

View:

```
@model CardsViewModel

@foreach (var post in Model.PostCard)
{
    <div>
        <p>ID: @post.Id</p>
        
    </div>
}
```

My initial seed data:

[image]

When I pass in the id value as 1:

[image]

I can get the data in page:

[image]